# Apply gradient to viewcontrollers view inside UIScrollView

Tags: ios

I have a view controller which contains a scroll view. Inside this scroll view I load 3 view controllers. For everyone I apply a gradient to `self.view`:

```
override func viewDidLayoutSubviews() {
    super.viewDidLayoutSubviews()

    let gradient = CAGradientLayer()
    gradient.frame = view.frame
    gradient.colors = [UIColor.morningTop, UIColor.morningMiddle, UIColor.morningBottom]
    view.layer.insertSublayer(gradient, at: 0)
}
```

When I run my app, the gradient is applied only on the first view controller.

I can't seem to understand why is this happening. Anyone has an idea ?

Comment: Elaborate more with screenshot or code

Answer (score 0):

I managed to fix this issue by changing this line:

```
gradient.frame = view.frame
```

to:

```
gradient.frame = view.bounds
```